# java : Inverted string triangle using recursion?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that accept a string and print an
 inverted triangle from it. For example, if I had
 `trianglePrint("abcdefgh")`, the output would be

```
abcdefgh  
 abcfgh   
  abgh 
   ab
```

It kinda of works...it's just that I'm getting the following errors

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
 -1 at Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:39) at Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:43) at
 Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:43) at
 Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:43) at
 Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:43) at
 Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:17) at
 Triangle.main(Triangle.java:6)
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Suggestions on a more
 efficient way to code this, will be appreciated too.

```
public class Triangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        trianglePrint("abcdefgh");
    }
    public static void trianglePrint(String string)
    {
        int length,terms ;
        length =string.length() ;
        if (length%2==0)
            terms = (length/2);
        else
            terms = (length/2) +1 ;

        trianglePrint(string,terms,length);
    }
    public static void trianglePrint(String string,int terms,int length)
    {
         String [] Array = new String [terms]; 
         int padterm= length ;

        /*if (length%2==0)
            terms = (length/2);
        else
            terms = (length/2) +1 ;
        */


        if (terms == 1)
            if (length%2==0)
               Array[0]=pad(string.substring(0,2),padterm) ;

            else
                Array[0]=pad(string.substring(0,1),padterm) ;
        else


                    Array[terms-1]=pad((string.substring(0, terms)
                               +string.substring(length-terms)),padterm);
            //use to monitor value of term
            System.out.println(terms);
                //used to monitor actual array content
            System.out.println(Array[terms-1]);
            trianglePrint(string,(terms-1),length);



    }
    public static void printList(String[] list,int position)
    {
        if (position < list.length)
            System.out.println(list[position]);
                printList(list,position+1);
    }
//pads with appropriate spaces
    public static String pad(String string,int length)
    {
        String result ;
        if (string.length() >= length)
            result = string ;
        else
            result = pad(" "+ string+" " ,length);
        return result ;
    }


 }
```

Comment: Looks like you have checked an array index of -1 in your printing method.

Comment: In the last part of the triangle, shouldn't bg be removed, and it should be ah instead of ab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a condition to stop the recursion. If `terms` is 0, then  `Array[terms-1]` will cause Exception, like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
     at Triangle.trianglePrint(Triangle.java:46)
```

So when variable `temrs` becomes 0, we need to stop recursion. You can add the following code to `trianglePrint` method, which will make your program work.

```
if(0 == terms)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Change

```
public static void trianglePrint(String string,int terms,int length)
{
```

to

```
public static void trianglePrint(String string,int terms,int length)
{
    if(0 == terms)
    {
       return;
    }
```

**Output in console;**

```
4
abcdefgh
3
 abcfgh 
2
  abgh  
1
   ab
```

Comment: Thanks!! This solved my problem....I'm not sure if this is a silly question...but why doesn't the program stop calling itself at terms==1(base case)? Also,if my return type is no longer "void" but "String [] " how could I make it work? I know using "return;" for the base case when terms==0 will no longer work because it will affect actual array return value...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing recursion to simply decrement the terms argument. This is not a good use of recursion (outside of a functional programming language optimized for tail recursion) and would be better implemented using a for loop. The good recursive paradigm for this would be to actually shorten the string:

```
public static void trianglePrint(String string) {
    trianglePrint(string, 0);
}
public static void trianglePrint(String string, int padding) {
    for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(string);
    if (string.length > 2) {
        int midpoint = string.length()/2; //assumes string length is even
        trianglePrint(string.substring(0, midpoint - 1) + string.substring(midpoint + 1), padding + 1);
    }
}
```

Not necessarily the fastest code, but very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote new code to solve the problem for you, using recursion. I believe it is both shorter and more efficient than your existing solution. An assumption goes into this: the strings have an even number of digits (you didn't explain how to handle odd number of digits)

```
public static void solve(String word) {
    solve(word, 0);
}

public static void solve(String word, int it) {
    // print starting spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < it; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");

    // print out string
    System.out.print(word);

    // print new line
    System.out.println();

    if(word.length() > 2) {
        int newlengthperside = (word.length() - 2)/2;
        solve( word.substring(0, newlengthperside) + word.substring(word.length() - newlengthperside), it+1);
    }
}
```

To understand this code, first look at the main method. We have a for loop that prints out a certain number of spaces before the string, based on the variable passed to the method, then we print out the string, then we print out a new line. Afterwards, we determine if the length of the string is not finished yet, and we take the left side and the right side of the new string, and call the method again. This recursion will terminate once the string has less than or equal to 2 characters.

We also make the method easy to use by overloading the method with another solve that just takes in a word, and calls the main solve method with that word and 0, the number of spaces to initially print.

Comment: you are 15 seconds too late :P

Comment: Haha yes, looks like our great minds think alike :). You might want to check your substring though, I think he wants to remove the two characters in the middle not at the end.

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread the expected output. Well, I went and implemented my substring in a way that is equally computationally complex and that I think is less confusing, so there :P

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm (as I understand it), seems to simplify into this

```
public static void trianglePrint(String in,
    int offset) {
  if (offset >= in.length()) { // Terminating condition.
     return;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(offset); // For padding.
  for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
    sb.append(' ');
  }
  final String padding = sb.toString(); // This is the padding, so don't clear.
  sb.append(in); // Add the current input.
  sb.append(padding); // Add more "invisible" padding.
  System.out.println(sb.toString()); // print it.
  int left = in.length() / 2; // One half.
  String lh = in.substring(0, left - 1); // the left.
  String rh = in.substring(left + 1, in.length()); // the right.
  trianglePrint(lh + rh, offset + 1); // recurse.
}

public static void trianglePrint(String in) {
  trianglePrint(in, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach can simplify further by leveraging the recursion more fully for the padding.  StringBuilder also makes it easier to delete from the middle of a string:

```
public static void trianglePrint2(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    int mid = s.length()/2;
    if (!s.replace(" ", "").equals(""))  //if not all spaces
        trianglePrint(" " + new StringBuilder(s).delete(mid-1, mid+1) + " ");
}
```

or alternatively (more efficient):

```
public static void trianglePrint(String s) {
    trianglePrint(s, s.length()/2);
}
public static void trianglePrint(String string, int mid) {
    System.out.println(s);
    if (string.length() > mid)
         trianglePrint(" " + new StringBuilder(s).delete(mid-1, mid+1), mid);
}
```

Both will work with odd or even lengths.